# How to customize theme in Vuetify using Storybook 6?

Tags: javascript, webpack, storybook

I want to customize themes in Vuetify using Storybook 6 and I am using `@socheatsok78/storybook-addon-vuetify` package https://storybook.js.org/addons/@socheatsok78/storybook-addon-vuetify

I did exactly what documentation says but theme is still not working at all. I want to configure vuetify with custom properties and with my own color palette.

`preview.js`

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!./main.scss';
import {
  withVuetify,
  withThemeProvider,
} from '@socheatsok78/storybook-addon-vuetify/dist/decorators';
import minifyTheme from 'minify-css-string';

export const globalTypes = {
  theme: {
    dark: false,
    options: {
      customProperties: true,
      minifyTheme,
    },
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: '#007BBF',
        secondary: '#008574',
      },
      dark: {
        primary: '#f099aa',
      },
    },
  },
};

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
};

export const decorators = [withThemeProvider, withVuetify];
```

`main.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-docs',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/preset-scss',
    '@socheatsok78/storybook-addon-vuetify',
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
          options: {
            resources: path.resolve(__dirname, 'main.scss'),
          },
        },
      ],
      sideEffects: true,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed the theme, you can find an tutorial how to do this and with all working code down below.
I found a great explanation here:

https://morphatic.com/2020/09/30/configuring-storybook-6-for-vue-2-vuetify-2-3/

`preview.html`

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!./main.scss';
import { withVuetify } from '@socheatsok78/storybook-addon-vuetify/dist/decorators';
import vuetify from './vuetify';

import Vue from 'vue';

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
};

export const decorators = [
  (story, context) => {
    const wrapped = story(context);

    return Vue.extend({
      vuetify,
      components: { wrapped },
      template: `
        <v-app>
          <v-container fluid>
            <wrapped/>
          </v-container>
        </v-app>
    `,
    });
  },
  withVuetify,
];
```

`main.js`

I removed one line from addons

`'@socheatsok78/storybook-addon-vuetify',`

`vuetify.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import minifyTheme from 'minify-css-string';
import theme from './theme';
import LRU from 'lru-cache';

const themeCache = new LRU({
  max: 10,
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60, // 1 hour
});

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    options: {
      customProperties: true,
      minifyTheme,
      themeCache,
    },
    themes: {
      light: theme,
    },
  },
});
```

`theme.js`

```
export default {
  // ... other colors
  primary: '#007BBF',
};
```

Theme works perfect now, only variables are not loaded correctly and I don't know how to solve this, you can read about it in the article comments